# Create Arabic msi (or any other locale, that is not listed in visual studio) using visual studio

Tags: windows-installer, orca

I have created a msi project in visual studio. I use ORCA to edit the msi. I need a msi installer for Arabic language, how can i create it using visual studio and applying transform files.

Arabic is not listed in visual studio msi 2008 project language settings.

Answer (score 0):

You open the English MSI file with Orca and translate everything to Arabic, that's the only choice as far as I know. You start with Transform->New, then make the changes. In the View->Summary Information change the language from 1033 to the Arabic value.  You probably need to go to Tools->Codepage to change that for the Arabic character set. When done, Transform->Generate transform.

Comment: Thanks PhilDW, yes we need to change the code page, otherwise the arabic characters are not shown properly.
I am using wilangid.vbs from the sdk to change the code page, then i apply the arabic transform.